# SQL Loader - CSV Import - control file - no data type is supporting NUMBER type

Tags: oracle12c, sql-loader

Below pasted the content of our control file:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/opt/home/myuser/username/Myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE TempArt
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ARTICLE_NUMBER,
ORDER_SIZE,
ORDER_QUANTITY INTEGER (8)
)
```

values available in CSV for the column ORDER_QUANTITY are 78, 89, 191, 212 etc., I expect the same values to be appearing on the console once i run select * from table_name; but the i am seeing some converted numbers, have used all the suitable data types for ORDER_QUANTITY for nothing worked so far. Can someone assist here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the target `tempart` table DDL, sample data as it appears in your CSV file, and the results you get and expect when you query the table. All three columns sound like they would be `number` in the database, so not sure why you are treating the quantity differently?